# JavaScript Accessing literal object property

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm trying to make this function that tells me which guitar I can purchased based on the budged. My issue is that I created a literal object and all outputs are giving the same answer (Except condition one) because I am trying to access the properties inside.

What would be the best way to access the property that has the name of the item?
Also, please correct any wrong terminology I use.

```js
let instruments = {
    guitar1: ["Gibson SG", "$3500"],
    guitar2: ["Fender Strat", "$3000"],
    guitar3: ["Ibanez JEM Custom", "$4200"],
};

function howMuchMoney() {
    let money = prompt("What's your budget?");

    if (money < 3000) {
        alert("Broke");
    } else if (money >= 3000) {
        alert(`Buy the ${instruments.guitar1[0]}`);
    } else if (money >= 3000) {
        alert(`Buy the ${instruments.guitar2[0]}`);
    } else if (money >= 4200) {
        alert(`Buy the ${instruments.guitar3[0]}`);
    }
}

howMuchMoney();
```

Comment: They're all giving the same value because your `else...if` tests are in the wrong order. You're checking if the value is greater than or equal to 3000 before checking if it's greater than or equal to the other values which are larger.

Comment: If `money` is 4500, you want the last case to match, right? You want to suggest the `Ibanez JEM Custom`. But you'll never do that because the second check you make (`money >= 3000`) returns true. You'll always suggest the `Gibson SG` and because you're using `else...if`, you only make the first suggestion that matches.

Comment: If you're going to use `else...if` and check if `money >= X`, then the largest value of `X` needs to be first, then the next largest, etc...

Comment: you will always get `Gibson SG` if the money `>= 3000` . as you made it in the condition, and it will always be fulfilled.

Comment: in addition to the points made above, note that `prompt` returns a *String*, which you'll need to explicitly convert to a number if you want these comparisons to work as intended. (For example, as strings 100000 is very definitely less than 3000.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues with your program:

##### `prompt()` returns a string

[`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) returns a string but you want to do comparisons on numbers so you need to convert the string to a number first using [`Number.parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). Otherwise you will just be checking on a lexicographic basis which could potentially give you unexpected results.

##### Order of `else if`s

You need to arrange your else if statements in a way that every else if could actually be reached otherwise there is no point defining those other cases as only ever one can be triggered. So arrange them from most money to least money when using `<=`.

Just a remark: Try to use `const` instead of `let` whenever you are not changing the value which is (or should be) almost always.

```js
const instruments = {
  guitar1: ["Gibson SG", "$3500"],
  guitar2: ["Fender Strat", "$3000"],
  guitar3: ["Ibanez JEM Custom", "$4200"],
};

while (true) {
  // we get a string here
  const moneyStr = prompt(`What's your budget?\n(Enter "exit" to end program)`);
  // end the inifinite loop if someone has entered "exit"
  if (moneyStr === "exit" || moneyStr === null) break;
  // parse the string to a float number
  const money = Number.parseFloat(moneyStr);
  // if the string cannot be parsed show error message and go to next iteration in loop meaning we ask for the input again
  if (isNaN(money)) {
    alert("Invalid input. Budget must be a number!");
    continue;
  }
  // money is now a number
  tellGuitar(money);
  break;
}

/**
 * Tell user which guitar to buy
 * @param {number} money money the user has
 */
function tellGuitar(money) {
  // broke first
  if (money < 3000) {
    alert("Broke");
    // now go from most mones to least money as otherwise the other cases will never trigger
  } else if (money >= 4200) {
    alert(`Buy the ${instruments.guitar3[0]}`);
  } else if (money >= 3500) {
    alert(`Buy the ${instruments.guitar1[0]}`);
  } else if (money >= 3000) {
    alert(`Buy the ${instruments.guitar2[0]}`);
  }
}
```

For reason of simplicity I have wrapped the program in an infinite loop when an invalid input is entered that cannot be converted to a number. To exit the program despite the infinite loop I have added an `exit` command. The program will also exit when `Cancel` is pressed (i.e. `prompt()` returns `null`). The actual logic to tell the user which guitar to buy was factored out into another method `tellGuitar()` which receives the money as a number.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be able to support the hypothetical case of if your instruments array hypothetically contained millions of instruments. That way, you won't hardcode any values. Check this solution.

```html
<button onclick="sendPrompt()">Click me</button>

<script>
    const instruments = {
        guitar1: ['Gibson SG', '$3500'],
        guitar2: ['Fender Strat', '$3000'],
        guitar3: ['Ibanez JEM Custom', '$4200'],
        guitar4: ['Jimi Hendrix Golden Limited Edition', '$500000000']
    };

    const calculateInstrument = (instruments, money) => {
        let bestOption = {
            diff: null,
            name: null,
        };

        for (const [name, price] of Object.values(instruments)) {
            const parsed = +price.slice(1);
            const diff = money - parsed;

            if (diff === 0) return name;

            if ((bestOption.diff > diff && diff > 0) || diff > 0) bestOption = { name, diff };
        }

        return bestOption.name;
    };

    const sendPrompt = () => {
        const val = prompt("What's your budget?");

        if (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(val)) return alert('Error! Only numbers!');

        const name = calculateInstrument(instruments, +val);

        if (!name) return alert('You broke.')
        alert(`You should buy ${name}`);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made you a solution using the `map()` method, which allows you to go through all the keys, getting only those keys whose price matches the specified budget of variable `money`.

Output the result in the `console`.

*For example:*

if you specify a budget as `$4000`, you will get a list of all guitars of equal and lesser value.

```js
let instruments = {
    guitar1: ["Gibson SG", "$3500"],
    guitar2: ["Fender Strat", "$3000"],
    guitar3: ["Ibanez JEM Custom", "$4200"],
};

function howMuchMoney() {
    let money = prompt("What's your budget?");

    Object.keys(instruments).map((key, index) => {
        let price = instruments[key][1].replace("$", "");

        if (price <= money) {
            console.log(instruments[key][0]);
        }
    });
}

howMuchMoney();
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied, some of the concepts are a little too advanced for me and I've been testing your responses for about 2 hours. I already solved the issue, I am just trying to understand whatever went beyond my reach.